# Running a Bokeh app with custom SQL-database

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, bokeh

I was just wondering if it would be possible to run a web-based application (showing interactive plots etc) using e.g. Bokeh where the data is based on a local SQL-database/server? What I am trying to achieve is for non-Python users to be able to interactively filter data (using sliders etc) in a Chrome-browser and interact with the database. The "core" functionality would be built and run on Python (as I would need user defined functions to be run on the data, and preferrably using pandas DataFrames for this).

Is this sort of solution possible, or is there a better way for this?

Thanks

Comment: check flask  you might be able to do it, only wildcard is bokeh

Comment: I'd suggest Tornado instead of Flask since Bokeh is built on Tornado. Either way what you want is indeed possible - just run a Bokeh server where each callback triggers an SQL query and sends its result back to Bokeh.